# Ошибка сборки Nextron

Tags: node.js, webpack, electron

Пытаюсь использовать ssh2-sftp-client вместе с Nextron, все отлично работает до тех пор пока не доходит до сборки самой программы.

При сборке программы с помощью команды

```
nextron build --win --x64
```

Выдает следующее:

```
> my-nextron-app@1.0.0 build
> nextron build

[nextron] Clearing previous builds
[nextron] Building renderer process
warn  - Invalid next.config.js options detected: 
  - The value at .images.path must be 1 character or more but it was 0 characters.

See more info here: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/invalid-next-config
info  - Linting and checking validity of types
info  - Using wasm build of next-swc
warn  - Attempted to load @next/swc-win32-x64-gnu, but it was not installed
warn  - Attempted to load @next/swc-win32-x64-msvc, but it was not installed
info  - Creating an optimized production build
Failed to compile.

../node_modules/ssh2/lib/protocol/crypto/build/Release/sshcrypto.node
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '�' (1:2)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
(Source code omitted for this binary file)

Import trace for requested module:
../node_modules/ssh2/lib/protocol/crypto/build/Release/sshcrypto.node
../node_modules/ssh2/lib/protocol/crypto.js
../node_modules/ssh2/lib/client.js
../node_modules/ssh2/lib/index.js
../node_modules/ssh2-sftp-client/src/index.js
../main/client.jsx
../main/actions.js


> Build failed because of webpack errors
```

package.json

```
{
  "private": true,
  "name": "program",
  "description": "",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "author": "",
  "main": "app/background.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nextron",
    "build": "nextron build",
    "postinstall": "electron-builder install-app-deps",
    "build:win32": "nextron build --win --ia32",
    "build:win64": "nextron build --win --x64"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^5.3.2",
    "electron-serve": "^1.1.0",
    "electron-store": "^8.1.0",
    "find-process": "^1.4.7",
    "react-bootstrap-icons": "^1.10.3",
    "ssh2": "^1.15.0",
    "ssh2-sftp-client": "^10.0.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^20.11.16",
    "@types/react": "18.2.55",
    "css-loader": "^6.10.0",
    "electron": "^21.3.3",
    "electron-builder": "^23.6.0",
    "next": "^12.3.4",
    "nextron": "^8.5.0",
    "node-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "sass": "^1.70.0",
    "sass-loader": "^14.1.0",
    "typescript": "5.3.3"
  }
}
```

next.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  webpack: (config, options) => {
    if (!options.isServer) {
      config.target = "electron-renderer";
    }
    
    return config;
  },
  images: {
    loader: "akamai",
    path: "",
  },
};
```

Comment: а вы пробовали гуглить?

Comment: https://github.com/mscdex/ssh2/issues/1213#issuecomment-1570351744

Comment: https://github.com/mscdex/ssh2/issues?q=is%3Aissue+electron

Comment: Весь день гуглил, так сам и не нашел. Но ссылки выручили! Спасибо!

Comment: да, тут нужен навык. мой ход мысли "так, сборка под электрон модуля с биндигами, значит надо идти в issues этого модуля на гитхаб и искать там"

Comment: Никогда не знал что это так делается, учту это. Спасиб, выручили :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Помогли изменения в next.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  webpack: (config, options) => {
    if (!options.isServer) {
      config.target = "electron-renderer";
    }
    config.plugins.push(
      new options.webpack.IgnorePlugin({
        resourceRegExp: /(cpu-features|sshcrypto\.node)/u,
      })
    );
    return config;
  },
  images: {
    loader: "akamai",
    path: "",
  },
};
```